# Where clause to search for 15 different values in one of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an accurate and working query, to pull CSR phone data, but I've been testing it only on one CSR extension. Now that it's working, I want to apply it to all 15 CSRs.

The query:

```
 SELECT
        sum(Duration) AS total_talk_time_seconds
      , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS total_talk_time_minutes
      , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS total_outbound
      , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 1) AS total_inbound

FROM cdrdb.session a
    INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
      ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
    where date(b.ts) >= curdate()
    AND 7200 in (callingpartyno, finallycalledpartyno);
```

However, I want to modify my where clause so instead of it saying "select where extension 7200 is in callingpartyno and finallycalledpartyno" It would say `select the calls where (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312) IN (callingpartyno, finallycalledpartyno)`

But I know that syntax won't work because it would expect 15 columns.

Here's some sample data for a quick idea:

```
    callingpartyno | finallycalledpartyno 
    -------------------------------------
    1234                outside   
    1234                outside   
    1234                outside   
    outsidecall         1234          
    outsidecall         1234          
    outsidecall         1234          
    9876                outside   
    9876                outside   
    9876                outside   
    outsidecall         9876         
    outsidecall         9876                  
    outsidecall         9876
```

For instance, extension 1234 has 6 calls, but in the table you would only know that by including both of those columns.

What's the best/most accurate and performant way for me to apply my query to that array of extensions?

Comment: If you have a follow up question involving an aggregation, then feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeat the list per column, e.g.

```
select * 
from calls 
where callingpartyno IN (7276,7314, 7295, 7306,7357,7200,7218,7247 7331,7255,7330,7000,7215, 7240,7358,7312) 
OR  finallycalledpartyno IN (7276,7314, 7295, 7306,7357,7200,7218,7247 7331,7255,7330,7000,7215, 7240,7358,7312)
```

Comment: Thank you, so this actually works but now I have one question: This returns one row with total cumulative data. Is there a way I could treat each 4 digit extension (whether in called number or calling number) as the user ID or extension and group by that so that I would have 15 rows each with their own totals?

Comment: Do you want to group by the calling or called party (or both)?

Comment: Both technically. So if 7276 had 6 calls as calling and 6 calls as called, that would be one row for extension 7276 with 12 total calls. So if it's the same 4 digit extension in each column I want to group by that, treating it as that user's extension ID